# How to test with Protractor that an AngularJS md-tooltip is displayed

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor, angularjs-material

Given an icon with a tooltip with the following template:

```html
<md-icon class="message-icon" md-svg-icon="message">
  <md-tooltip md-direction="top">
    <div class="tooltip-row">
      My tooltip text
    </div>
  </md-tooltip>
</md-icon>
```

I would like to test with [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/#/) that when the mouse cursor is hovering the icon the [md-tooltip](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTooltip) is displayed and the text matches `My tooltip text`.

By inspecting the page I noticed when the tooltip is displayed the following piece of html is appended at the bottom of the `<body>` element:

```html
<div class="md-panel-outer-wrapper">
  <md-tooltip md-direction="top" class="ng-isolate-scope md-panel _md-panel-offscreen">
    <div class="tooltip-row ng-binding">Some random note</div>
  </md-tooltip>
</div>
```

In light of that, I wrote the following test:

```
describe('message icon', () => {
  it('should display a tooltip when the mouse is hovering the icon', () => {
    const messageIcon = $('.message-icon');
    browser.actions().mouseMove(messageIcon).perform().then(() => {
      const tooltip = $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper');
      browser
        .wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(tooltip), 5000, 'Expected tooltip to appear')
        .then(() => {
           expect(tooltip.getText()).toBe('My tooltip text');
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Unfortunately this test fails with a different error message each time is executed:

- *Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .md-panel-outer-wrapper)*
- *Failed: Expected tooltip to appear. Wait timed out after 5005ms*

By setting the timeout to 10 seconds I also get an additional error:

- *Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.*

Does anyone know how to properly write such a test?

EDIT:

Adding relevant devDependencies:

```
{
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-reporters": "^2.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "protractor-console": "~3.0.0",
    "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "~0.5.0",
}
```

Comment: btw. does the test perform mouseOver action? You probably got the timeout error because timeout in `ExpectedConditions` is greater than `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`

Comment: there comes debugging.Break your test into several pieces and make sure each of them works to at least narrow down the possible problem, because I'll tell you there could be 100 of reasons in your case. As such make sure locators are accurate (by using .isPresent()),then pause your test after hovering over the icon to see if the tooltip is actually showing up.If it does,it is possible because of specific layouts you may wanna wait for visibility of `.md-panel-outer-wrapper .tooltip-row`element.And lastly may be you don't need to wait for visibility but instead wait for presence of the element

Answer (score 2):

Tooltips can be tricky and may be hard to right a test for.  Here are two things I would suggest trying:

(1) After your first hover, try triggering it with a minor mousemove.  I don't have an explanation why it wouldnt show up the first time, but I've encountered the same with a tooltip and this helped.

(2) If you're still getting `No element found` errors, add a wait for `presenceOf` before `visibilityOf` (or combine them using `and`):

```
    browser.actions().mouseMove(messageIcon).perform().then(() => {
        // perform another mousemove to try and trigger tooltip
        browser.actions().mouseMove({x: 5, y: 5}).perform();
        const tooltip = $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper');
        // wait for present AND visible
        const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
        const visible = EC.visibilityOf(tooltip);
        const present = EC.presenceOf(tooltip);
        browser.wait(EC.and(present, visible), 5000, 'Expected tooltip to appear').then(() => {
            expect(tooltip.getText()).toEqual('My tooltip text');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Very good points! Unfortunately they didn't help to make the test pass. What puzzles me is its indetermination: on some runs the test passes successfully (I can see the tooltip being displayed in the browser), on some others inexplicably it doesn't (I don't see the tooltip)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This actually works pretty good and saved me even more time.
It's kind of tricky, i've also find out that triggering `.click()` on the tooltip pops the tooltip content just for an instant and then closes it back.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `tooltip = $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper');`  try using  `element(by.id('md-panel-outer-wrapper'))`. In my case this worked. And then use `getText()` to get the text.

The `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL` is appearing due to the default timeout value in your configuration file. You can change this value if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip is `ElementFinder` type, so you need to change expect to:

`expect(tooltip.getText()).toBe('My tooltip text');`

EDIT:

```
describe('message icon', () => {
  it('should display a tooltip when the mouse is hovering the icon', () => {
    const messageIcon = $('.message-icon');
    browser.actions().mouseMove(messageIcon).perform().then(() => {
      const tooltip = $('.md-panel-outer-wrapper');
      browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(tooltip), 5000, 'Expected tooltip to appear').then(() => {
        expect(tooltip.getText()).to.eventually.equals.('My tooltip text');
      });

    });
  });
});
```

`getText()` returns a promise, so you should use chai-as-promised lib

Comment: `expect` can handle promises, no need to add a lib for that.  Based on his syntax, he seems to be using `jasmine` anyway